# Read buffer as matrix using X and Y values in C

Tags: c, matrix, int, unsigned-char

I have a buffer that contains 256 integers, so creating a 16x16 matrix. What I'm trying to accomplish is reading a value stored in the buffer as if it were a matrix.
So if I give coordinates of 5 and 3, I should get the value where Y is 5, and Y is X.

For example, here is a small portion of the buffer, but in a 16x3 matrix for easy reading, and consider this a starting index of 0 rather than 1)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So if I were to try to get the values at say, Y = 2, and X = 5, I should return the value 9.

Here is some of the code I have already, but my math is off.

```
unsigned char getTablevalue(int tableIndex, unsigned char *buffer) {
    return buffer[tableIndex];
}

void getInput(....) {
    int yValue = 2;
    int xValue = 5;
    int returnValue = 0;
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(256 * sizeof (unsigned char));
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);

    ... Some code to fill buffer...
    returnValue = getTablevalue({what can I put here}, buffer); 

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiply col by 16 and add row.  There's your index.

Comment: `yValue * 16 + xValue`. Of course, it all depends on whether you filled the buffer correctly.

Comment: Why not use a 2D array?

Comment: With some tweaking for indexes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you much. Sometimes the basics just get passed over...

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrates using a buffer as an array and copying the buffer 'array' into a real array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int x, y;
    int arr[16][16];
    int xtest =2, ytest =12; //'random values to test that it works

    /* allocate space for a buffer of 256 values in the range 0 to 255) */
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(256 * sizeof (unsigned char));

    /* fill the buffer with sequential values from 0 to 255 */
    for (n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        buffer[n] = n;
    }

    /* just to check the fill was OK - print out the buffer contents */
    for (n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        printf("%d .. ", buffer[n]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

   /* fill a 16 * 16 array with values from the buffer
       that the buffer data is arranged in 16 groups of 16 values in a 
       single sequential buffer */
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            arr[x][y] = buffer[(x * 16) + y];
        }
    }

    /* print out the array */
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    /* just print a 'random' xy value from the matrix and from the buffer
       they will be the same (we hope) */
    printf("X=%d,Y=%d, Matrix[%d][%d] is: %d ... and Buffer %d,%d is %d\n",
            xtest, ytest, xtest, ytest, arr[xtest][ytest],
            xtest, ytest, buffer[(xtest * 16) + ytest]);
    if (arr[xtest][ytest] == buffer[(xtest * 16) + ytest]) {
        printf("Wow - they ARE the same\n");
        } else {
        printf("Oh No - they are different\n");
    }
}
```

Sample output
`X=2,Y=12, Matrix[2][12] is: 44 ... and Buffer 2,12 is 44
Wow - they ARE the same`

Comment: That's really awesome of you, thank you. I was able to adopt a few of these things. What would be a higher performance hit, reading from buffer, or moving to an array. A call will be made to check values 256 times (to get each value) for specific input.

Comment: I don't know enough to say if one or other is the best.  However there is a lot of information available about conventional arrays, including how they are passed to functions and how arrays can be accessed - not just by '[ ]' subscripts but also by manipulating pointers to arrays, so I would certainly go for conventional arrays - but it's all good learning.

If you thought my answer was useful please give it a +1 or an accept - or not - your call.